# Any place to learn spring batch with JSL

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch and Job Specification Language (JSL). I am looking for some example/guide developing spring batch project using JSL. Can recommend me some sites or books for me to read?

Comment: very useful resource you can start with: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/batch-processing004.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point would the section from the reference documentation about JSR-352: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/jsr-352.html#jsr-352. There is a toggle at the top of the page that allows you to choose how to show samples (in either XML of Java configuration). You can also find samples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples.